# Why does my AutoIt script compile but doesn't do anything?

Tags: autoit

My AutoIt script compiles but doesn't do what it's supposed to do. Code:

```
HotKeySet(+"{G}","gather")

While 1
    sleep(100)
WEnd

Global $charRunTimeS = 2;
Global $collectKey = "{LWIN}";
Global $vehicleInvKey = "{T}";
Global $charRunTimeMS = $charRunTimeS * 1000

Global $posItemX = 820;
Global $posItem1Y = 300;
Global $posItem2Y = 340;
Global $posItem3Y = 365;
Global $posItem4Y = 397;
Global $posBtnStore = 678;
Global $posItemSelectedY = $posItem4Y

Func gather()

$counter = 0;
While $counter <= 2

    Send("{s down}")
    Sleep($charRunTimeMS)
    Send("{s up}")

    $counter1 = 0;
    While $counter1 <= 4
        Send($collectKey)
        Sleep(100)
        Send($collectKey)
        Sleep(30000)
        $counter1 = $counter1 + 1
    WEnd

    Send("{w down}")
    Sleep($charRunTimeMS)
    Send("{w up}")

    Send($vehicleInvKey)
    MouseClick("primary", $posItemX, $posItemSelectedY)

    $counter2 = 0;
    While $counter2 <= 30
        MouseClick($posItemX, $posBtnStore)
        $counter2 = $counter2 + 1
    WEnd

    Send("{ESC}")
    $counter = $counter + 1
WEnd

EndFunc
```

Output from de-bug. First line is when compiling and running, the second line is when I stop the code:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "C:\Users\RichusX\Desktop\AltisGatherScript.au3"
>
> Process failed to respond; forcing abrupt termination...
> Exit code: 1    Time: 14.39

Comment: Where is the function "gather" called?

Comment: @UweKeim from the `HotKeySet(+"{G}","gather")` , it was outside the codeblock due to formatting but should be inside from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all you need to do is write the call like this:

```
HotKeySet("G", "gather")
```

You do not need the +, because of the capital G. If you want to then you have to put it into to "". Have a look at the send function.